# What causes Scene Builder 100% cpu usage and unresponsiveness?

Tags: java, cpu-usage, scenebuilder

Scene Builder information:

```
Product Version
JavaFX Scene Builder 17.0.0

Build Information
Version 17.0.0
Date: 2021-09-29 13:41:03
JavaFX Version: 17
Java Version: 17, OpenJDK Runtime Environment
```

System information:

```
OS:  Kubuntu 20.04
RAM: 8GB
CPU: Intel core i5-7200U
```

After several hours (~3) having a project (.fxml file) open and as I was working on it, Scene Builder started using more cpu than usual and slowly became unresponsive. Cpu usage was increasing and hit ~100% after about 10 minutes since I noticed performance degradation. All I was doing seems pretty normal: adding new Controls, setting layout, adding internationalized strings, fx:id's...

Causes of this might be probably several. Just asking if anyone else had similiar problem.

Every time this happens, Scene Builder was opened for longer period of time (>2 hours), but does not happen on every time I open any project. It happens sometimes when I work on specific project that also use external css (not big) and internationalized strings from .properties file (around 600 key-values). I have not found out yet when specifically it starts ramping up cpu usage.

Maybe worth noting that operating system did not go to sleep or logout mode. RAM usage when it froze that so I could not use it anymore was 2GB almost exactly. And css and .properties file with internationalized strings are being edited during work on that project in Scene Builder (this might be the cause with that the fxml is not smallest one maybe??).

Maybe worth posting fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="1007.0" prefWidth="1437.0" stylesheets="@css/external.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="desktop.funeral.RomanCatholicMarriageController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
        <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.application">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#settings" text="%menuitem.settings" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openAbout" text="%menuitem.about" />
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logout" text="%menuitem.logout" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quit" text="%menuitem.quit" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.tools">
               <items>
                  <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menuitem.menu.import">
                    <items>
                      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#importFuneralAsObject" text="%menuitem.importentry.marriageasbin" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#importFuneralFromMatrika" text="%menuitem.importentry.marriagesfrommatrika" />
                    </items>
                  </Menu>
                  <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menuitem.menu.export">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exportFuneralAsBin" text="%menuitem.exportentryobject" />
                        <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="exportMarriageList" mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menuitem.export.marriage.marriagelist" />
                    </items>
                  </Menu>
               </items></Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <items>
            <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="backButt" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goBack" text="%button.back" textAlignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="705.0" spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="%filtertype.label" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="comboBoxFilterType" onAction="#filterTypeChanged" prefWidth="150.0" />
                        <TextField fx:id="textFieldFilter" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="comboBoxFilter" prefWidth="150.0" />
                        <Button fx:id="doFilterButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doFilter" text="%button.dofilter" />
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </HBox>
                  <Label fx:id="labelNumberOfEntries" text="XXX">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <content>
                        <TableView fx:id="tableView" onMouseClicked="#itemClicked" prefHeight="417.0" prefWidth="561.0">
                           <placeholder>
                              <Label text="%tableview.placeholder.empty" />
                           </placeholder>
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="brideColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="%marriage.bride" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="groomColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="%marriage.groom" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="marriageDateColumn" prefWidth="90.4000244140625" text="%marriage.tableview.marriagedate" />
                           </columns>
                           <columnResizePolicy>
                              <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                           </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TableView>
                     </content>
                  </ScrollPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true">
               <content>
                  <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane fx:id="gridPaneTopLevel" alignment="CENTER" hgap="6.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" vgap="4.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="25.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="25.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="25.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="25.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="25.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="25.0" />
                           </columnConstraints>
                           <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                           </rowConstraints>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="30.0" top="5.0" />
                           </padding>
                           <children>
                              <Label text="%entryview.createdlabel" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" />
                              <Label fx:id="created" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
                              <Label text="%entryview.updatedlabel" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" />
                              <Label fx:id="updated" GridPane.columnIndex="4" />
                              <Label text="%entryview.number.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bride.firstname.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groom.firstname.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridestate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                              <Label text="%entryview.page.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="%entryview.bundle.label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bride.lastname.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bride.church.label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groom.lastname.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groom.church.label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groomstate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="15" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.brideprofession.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.marriagedate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groomprofession.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="15" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.marriageplace.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridemothername.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridefathername.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridemotherreligion.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridefatherreligion.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groomfathername.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="17" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groommothername.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="16" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groommotherreligion.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="16" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groomfatherreligion.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="17" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridebirthdate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groombirthdate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="18" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridebirthplace.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groombirthplace.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="18" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridebaptismdate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groombaptismdate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="19" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.bridebaptismplace.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groombaptismplace.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="19" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.brideconfirmationdate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groomconfirmationdate.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="20" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.brideaddress.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="12" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.witness1name.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="23" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groomaddress.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="21" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.witness2name.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="23" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.witness1address.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="24" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.witness2address.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="24" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.witness1profession.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="25" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.witness2profession.label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="25" />
                              <Label text="%entryview.notes.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="26" GridPane.rowSpan="2" />
                              <Label text="%entryview.priest.label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <TextField fx:id="number" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField fx:id="page" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField fx:id="bundle" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <TextField fx:id="brideFirstName" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                              <TextField fx:id="brideLastName" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                              <TextField fx:id="groomFirstName" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
                              <TextField fx:id="groomLastName" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
                              <TextField fx:id="priest" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="25" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="24" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="24" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="25" />
                              <TextArea fx:id="notes" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="337.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.rowIndex="26" GridPane.rowSpan="2" />
                              <TextField fx:id="brideState" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                              <TextField fx:id="groomState" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="15" />
                              <TextField fx:id="brideProfession" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                              <TextField fx:id="groomProfession" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="15" />
                              <DatePicker fx:id="marriageDate" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField fx:id="marriagePlace" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <TextField fx:id="brideMotherName" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                              <TextField fx:id="brideFatherName" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
                              <TextField fx:id="groomMotherName" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="16" />
                              <TextField fx:id="groomFatherName" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="17" />
                              <TextField fx:id="groomMotherReligion" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="16" />
                              <TextField fx:id="groomFatherReligion" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="17" />
                              <DatePicker GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
                              <DatePicker GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="18" />
                              <DatePicker GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
                              <DatePicker GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="19" />
                              <DatePicker GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
                              <DatePicker GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="20" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="18" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="19" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="20" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.brideconfirmationplace.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.groomconfirmationplace.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="20" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="12" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="21" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.dispenses.label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="23" />
                              <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="23" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.bride" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.groom" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="13" />
                              <ComboBox prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                              <ComboBox prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
                              <ComboBox prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                              <ComboBox prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
                              <Label text="%marriage.entryview.witnesses.label" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="22" />
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                        <HBox fx:id="crudButtonsHBox" alignment="CENTER" spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                           <children>
                              <Button fx:id="newEntryButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newEntry" text="%registry.add.button" />
                              <Button fx:id="editButton" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editEntry" text="%registry.edit.button" />
                              <Button fx:id="deleteButton" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteEntry" text="%registry.delete.button" />
                              <Button fx:id="cancelButton" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancel" text="%registry.cancel.button" />
                              <Button fx:id="confirmButton" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#confirm" text="%registry.confirm.button" />
                           </children>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets bottom="15.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </HBox>
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**UPDATE:**
SceneBuilder seems to be using 2GB memory max by default (froze happened when it used 2GB), so I guess it ran out of memory.

[image: VisualVM]

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess but from the symptoms this looks like SceneBuilder is running out of memory. Maybe due to some memory leak. Could you check, e.g., via VisualVM, whether SceneBuilder is busy with only doing garbage collections?

Comment: It looks like it ran out of memory - judging by visual vm (default max heap - 2GB). How do I check if it is busy doing garbage collections?

Comment: In the Monitor tab and CPU graph you can see the GC activity in blue.

Comment: Place where GC activity should be is: CPU - Not supported for this JVM. Looks like it uses own OpenJDK 17. Is there a way to set custom jvm for Scene Builder? Have not found anything in scene builder installation conf files yet.

Comment: You can also observe the GC activity in the Heap tab instead of the CPU.